# How to simplify the SQL query with AND and OR operators to retrieve sums of particular columns?

Tags: sql

I want to get the sum of books and pens from the item table based on `comp_id` and `expirationdate` from tables item and plan.

Below is how the tables look like:

[image]

I want to get the sum of books and pens for `comp_id = 1`; the output should be 15 for books and 30 for pens.

I have this query and it works fine

```
SELECT SUM(books) AS books, SUM(pens) AS pens
FROM plan 
JOIN item ON plan.id = item.plan_id 
          AND item.comp_id = '1'  
          AND (item.expiry IS NULL OR item.expiry > NOW()) ;
```

How can I simply the above query?

Could someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can clarify why you want to simplify the query? It is not that complicated and seems to be written quite well in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few suggestions I could make.

1. Separate join condition from filter logic, this makes the intent of the query a bit more clear.
2. Use table alias
3. Use COALESCE(item.expiry, DATE '9999-12-31') which removes the OR condition.

```sql
SELECT SUM(p.books) AS books, SUM(p.pens) AS pens
FROM plan p
  JOIN item i ON i.plan_id = p.id
WHERE i.comp_id = '1'
  AND COALESCE(i.expiry, DATE '9999-12-31') > NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting from a rather large dataset, you may get better performance by not using a function inside of your JOIN.  You can declare a value for Now() at the top, and use the variable in your join.  That is one way to possible increase performance.  But in this tiny dataset it wont matter.  You could also separate the last part of your join into a where clause. It may optimize better.

```
DECLARE @date datetime
select @date = NOW()

SELECT SUM(books) AS books, SUM(pens) AS pens
FROM plan 
JOIN item ON plan.id = item.plan_id
WHERE item.comp_id = '1' AND (item.expiry IS NULL OR item.expiry > @date) ;
```